# Tipos Atômicos na linguagem C

Tags: c, característica-linguagem

Qual a diferença entre tipo primitivos e atômicos ?

Para que serve os tipos atômicos ?

Em quais situações eles são aplicados ?

Comment: É disso que está falando? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic

Comment: Sim,exatamente isso.

Comment: Sei lá, são conceitos tão diferentes que nem sei por onde começar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma grande diferença entre tipos **primitivos** e tipos **atômicos**.

Os tipos atômicos são livres de raças de dados e podem ser modificados e/ou acessados por duas threads diferentes. Um dado atômico é muito utilizado quando, por exemplo, temos 2 ações distintas que são executadas nesse dado, como leitura e gravação, esse tipo de dado também é muito utilizado em sistemas operacionais, onde é necessário que um dado seja acessado por threads distintas.

É errado dizer isso, mas ele seria algo próximo a uma operação assíncrona.

Comment: O que seria uma raça de dados? :)

Comment: O que seria raça de dados ?

Comment: Raça de dados seria uma maneira de dizer "tipos de dados" - int, float, etc...